# How do I count the number of comparisons in binary search program?

Tags: c++

I am trying the count the number of times comparisons happen during binary search. I need help to find where I should increment the count of comparisons.

This is what I have so far.

```
int min = 0;
  int max = list.size() - 1;
  this->comparisons = 0;
  while (max >= min) {
    int middle = (max + min) / 2;
    this->comparisons++;
    if (list[middle].comparedTo(key) == LESS) {
      min = middle + 1;
    } else if (list[middle].comparedTo(key) == GREATER) {
      max = middle - 1;
    } else {
      return middle;
return -1;
```

Comment: It's up to you. Normally, the comparison that's interesting to count is the one that's typically expensive -- that is when you're comparing the key. So, if you enter the `== LESS` block, you only performed one comparison. But if you enter either the `== GREATER` block or the `else` block, then you performed two comparisons.

Comment: You should only do `list[middle].comparedTo(key)` once. Save the result or use a `switch`.